# Why doesn't all localization for the app work?

Tags: android

I'm making an Android app and translating it with the Translation Editor in Android Studio. I wanna translate it to Norwegian, Danish and Swedish, and have made the following translations:

- da-rDK
- nb
- nb-rNO
- no
- sv
- sv-rSE

And these are the available selections in Android Studio for these languages. I tried to run the app on a Samsung S9, LG G4 and Asus Zenpad and switch between those languages. The problem is that only the Danish will work on all devices. Any ideas what might be wrong with the app?

For debugging purposes I added some code to my app to print the current locale on the phone. It's in the format `no_NB`, `da_DK` etc.

Comment: How do you switch the languages? Do you restart the app after the switch? Please clarify.

Comment: @leonardkraemer I switch in the phone settings. Also tried to restart app. Danish is not my primary language by the way. And I don't even need to completely restart the app for it to change to Danish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem and thought I should post my solution. It seems that the following was set in build.gradle

```
resConfigs "no-rNO","da-rDK"
```

When I removed that line everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a `values-da` resource folder for danish resources, covering all danish regions, meaning Danmark and Grønland. For me the solution to the missing translation was to add `da` to resConfigs like this:

```
resConfigs "da", "en", "sv"
```